# How to get data on database and display in "select" dropdown in view (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am a newbie to CodeIgniter, I have created a simple app that will fetch data from database and then display it in a `<SELECT>` dropdown. I'm trying to get data from a specific field from database to my view. So far, I have tried the code below (not working):

My model (datamodel.php),

```
function getbanklist() {
    $banklist = array();
    $this->db->select("id, bank");
    $this->db->from('bank');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows >= 1){
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
            $banklist[$row['id']]=$row['bank'];
        }
        return $banklist;
    }
}
```

My controller (home.php),

```
function index(){
    $data['bankdata'] = $this->datamodel->getbanklist();
    $this->load->view('viewdata', $data);
}
```

My view (viewdata.php),

```
<tr>
    <th>BANK</th>
    <td>
        <div class="containers">
            <select name="bank">
            <?php foreach($bankdata as $bank){
                echo '<option value="'.$bank['id'].'">'.$bank['bank'].'</option>';
            } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My database structure (see [here](http://prntscr.com/74mi6p)),

```
id    bank
------------
0     Bank 1
1     Bank 2
2     Bank 3
3     Bank 4
4     Bank 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Model:

```
function getbanklist() {
    $this->db->select("id,bank");
    $this->db->from('bank');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

In your view:

```
<select name="bank">
<?php foreach($bankdata->result() as $bank){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $bank->id ?>"><?php echo $bank->bank ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I got error, it shows error :  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in

Comment: did you change your model??

Comment: yes. I did. maybe I'm messing up with my code. I'll check all. thanks

Comment: it works. I messed up with my old code. thanks @KavinSmk

Answer (score 0):

How to pass database value to view page drop down list in codeingniter.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="department" id="department">
        <?php foreach($bankdata as $key => $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['dept_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['managers_name']; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>

    </select>
</div>
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function department()
{

    $this->load->model('insert_model');
    $data['bankdata'] = $this->insert_model->getbanklist();
    //$this->load->view('login_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
}
```

This is my model code:

```
function category_name_get()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query=$this->db->get('dept');//employee is a table in the database
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: It is not loading dropdown list in view page.